# XCUI Tests losing connection to device

Tags: ios, xcode7, ui-testing

I'm having trouble running some tests on real devices with the new XCUI Test in Xcode 7. I've written a simple monkey tester that performs various interactions with our app over a 10 minute period. This works fine using simulators, however with real devices it loses connection to the device after around 3-6 minutes, with the following appearing in the logs:

"Observed termination of tracker for token xxxxx for launch of xxxx"

To find the problem, I scaled the test back to just sit and sleep for 10 minutes, it works fine. I then introduced a swipe every 5 seconds, and immediately the connection issue reappears

I've tried all the obvious fixes, such as different devices, different machines, different cables etc

Any help hugely appreciated

Comment: Apologies, forget the 2nd log message: _finishWithError:Error Domain=XCDebuggerErrorDomain Code=0 "Lost connection to "iPad".

Comment: You're not alone. Same issue for me and I can't seem to track down the underlying issue. The simulator runs the test splendidly.